# How to exclude specific rows (based on a cell value) from this simple Excel formula calculating avarage price?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am absolutly not into Excel. I have a cell containing this formula:

```
=SUM(D2:D33)/SUM(F2:F33)
```

I want to adapt this formula in the following way: it has to skip a row (do not take into consideration in the previous formula. so the D cell value is not summed and the F value is not summed) if the B cell value has "SELL" as value.

it represents something like this related to a cryptocurrency calculator:

[image]

The **I2** cell contains the previous formula that calculate the average buying price. I want to exclude from this calculation the row representing a sell operation.

What can I do?

**EDIT-1:** tried with this formula but I am obtaining this error message:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D2:D6,B2:B6="BUY"))/SUM(FILTER(F2:F6,B2:B6="BUY"))
```

[image]

Comment: Answered here - https://superuser.com/questions/1317193/having-2-formulas-in-one-cell-in-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SUMIF()`. Try-

```
=SUMIF(B2:B6,"BUY",D2:D6)/SUMIF(B2:B6,"BUY",F2:F6)
```

Or `SUMPRODUCT()`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D2:D6)*(B2:B6="BUY"))/SUMPRODUCT((F2:F6)*(B2:B6="BUY"))
```

Or `FILTER()` formula with `Excel-365`.

```
=SUM(FILTER(D2:D6,B2:B6="BUY"))/SUM(FILTER(F2:F6,B2:B6="BUY"))
```

Comment: Only the second formula works (but I find some problem to understand how exactly works). The First and the last one it seems better to me but I obtain an error message with these 2 formula. I added the error to my original post. Tnx

Comment: @AndreaNobili `FILTER()` formula is only available to `Excel-365` version? Also for regional settings it may different separator like comma (,) or semicolon or decimal separator. Also please check that. First formula should work fine!

Comment: @AndreaNobili Try to replace `,` comma with semicolon `;` in formula for your region.

Comment: Yes, it was separator problem. Using ";" instead "," it worked. Tnx again